# .Net Core tag helper intellisense and color coding not working

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, intellisense, tag-helpers

I am having issues with .NET core and tag helpers. The color coding and the intellisense are not displaying or being registered when I type in asp-for. I've tried creating a new solution in a separate instance, verified that the intellisense works, and then copied the project.json into the project that doesn't have working intellisense/color coding, and it doesn't fix the issue.

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I've also made the reference/injection in the _ViewImports file for the mvc tag helpers. This is the view where I'm testing that it works.
[image]

And here is my project structure, just in case you can see something that I'm not seeing.

[image]

If it helps at all, here is the version of Visual Studio I am using.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this. 
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/484#issuecomment-219807702

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed it in two steps.

1.Install Razor tool from package manager console. It is pre-release for now

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools –Pre
```

2. Download and install [`Razor Language Services`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices) from marketplace. (Your visual studio instance should be closed)

After restart visual studio, intellisense and coloring should be working for tag helpers.

[image]

Comment: For VS2017, the Razor Language Services installation is the key. It started working only after installing this pack, even though the Nuget package for Razor Tools was already installed. Thanks!

Comment: This plus the `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` code in the _ViewImports.cshtml did it for me.

Comment: This was working nicely, but at VS2017 Version 15.3.0, it broke again  Please help!

Comment: didnt worked for me in 2019  Razor Language Services not installing

Answer (score 2):

This is a semi-old Q&A, but I recently solved a similar problem where [tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1) intellisense and highlighting/colorization suddenly stopped working, so I post this for posterity.

I tried to repair and reinstall Visual Studio to no avail. What ultimately solved this issue follows:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Download and install the latest [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).
3. Open "Apps & features" (Add or remove programs)
4. Search for ".NET Core SDK" and uninstall all except the latest version (x64 and/or x86).
5. Reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: I actually Did that. Reintall latest and fresh SDk(2.2) for both 64x & 86x , 
& runtime from official site and remove all 2.0 - 2.1(2nd last) sdk installers.
It actually did Work.
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

There is a BUG in .net, When you create project and name it starting with number, TagHelper  will not work,
in my project this was a problem

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please post it as a comment.

Comment: you are not right, this is the answer, read all not first word

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers and add below line in **_ViewImports.cshtml** file

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I had this issue recently, but the solution is a little bit different right now. To install the package in VS Code, run in terminal:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools --prerelease
```

If it doesn't solve, delete your .vscode folder inside your user folder and install C# and other extensions again.

You do not need to install Razor Language Services anymore. After restart VS Code, everything works again.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I was having a similar issue in my ASP .NET Core web app. My intellisense wasn't working, and my page wasn't binding to the model.
It was working fine when I was using the normal Controllers folder, but not when I tried using Areas.

[image]

I moved the _ViewStart.cshtml file out of the Views folder to make it accessible, but I didn't do the same for the _ViewImports.cshtml. Moving _ViewImports.cshtml into the main project directory fixed the problem for me.

I think it's because of this line.

[image]

Hope this helps someone!