# IntelliSense for Razor Pages routes

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I was toying with new Razor Pages in ASP .NET Core 2.0 and noticed some problems with IntelliSense.

When using tag helper for MVC controller I get usual help:

[image: MVC with IntelliSense]

However there is no such help for `asp-page` tag helper used in Razor Pages:

[image: razor Pages with no help]

Is this a problem with my Visual Studio or rather Razor Pages tags do not support it yet?

I use ASP .NET Core 2.0 with framework 4.7 on VS 2017 15.5.5.

Comment: Same for me: Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.2), asp.net core 2.1. Maybe there are any extensions?

Comment: Have you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924211/net-core-tag-helper-intellisense-and-color-coding-not-working

Comment: @KiranJoshi This adds autocompletion of tag helpers, but this doesn't add autocompletion inside asp-page helper. PS. I've tried to disable Resharper and intellisense for asp-action was switched off. So, this question is not about visual studio issue, but feature request for Resharper: add intellisense for razor pages.

Comment: @AK So intellisense for asp-action is an R# feature... Nice to know!

Comment: Resharper feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-472405

Answer (score 1):

It seems `IntelliSense` for routes is not supported (yet I hope), but there is an interesting workaround for that - see [Razor Pages Url tt File](http://kurtdowswell.com/software-development/razor-pages-url-tt-file/). The idea is to create some `SitePages.tt` file in your `ASP.NET Core 2` project using `Razor Pages` to scan the `/Pages` folder and output a class with string properties to get the `IntelliSense` for routes:

```
<cancel-button asp-page="@SitePages.DashboardIndex"></cancel-button>
```