# opening another form from an <a>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in Visual Studios 2017 with this block of code in it. I just went to remake it in on my work computer (running 2015). Is there a reason why the middle two links don't work anymore?

The code doesn't even turn purple in the IDE. The top screenshot is from my laptop, the bottom screenshot is from my work computer (where the trouble is) https://gyazo.com/2968018e89c24748d48cb2291dce50d3?token=e038af6931608caede27c103a0365184

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="well well-sm" style="background-color:lightcyan">
        <h4>AVAS for Opperations</h4>
        <div class="list-group">

            <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398939" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(Make charts of buses passing timepoints!)">AVAS Time-Space Chart <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/education-set-4/512/information-512.png" class="w3-round" alt="Denmark" style="width:3%"></a>
            <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398939" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(Make a list of Route and Logon events from a bus, run or O/B)">History by Bus/Run/Operator <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/education-set-4/512/information-512.png" class="w3-round" alt="Denmark" style="width:3%"></a>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Legal" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(Make a list of stops and timepoints for a bus for an hour)">Bus-Hour History <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/education-set-4/512/information-512.png" class="w3-round" alt="Denmark" style="width:3%"></a>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Legal" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(Make a list of buses passing a selected stop)">Bus-Stop History <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/education-set-4/512/information-512.png" class="w3-round" alt="Denmark" style="width:3%"></a>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing [Razor Language Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices).

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924211/net-core-tag-helper-intellisense-and-color-coding-not-working).