# .Net Core tag helper intellisense not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having issues with .NET core and tag helpers. the IntelliSense is not displaying or being registered when I type in asp-for. IntelliSense,  it doesn't fix the issue.

[image: ViewImport.cshtml]

[image]

[image: itis at my view]

I've also made the reference/injection in the _ViewImports file for the mvc tag helpers.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.TagHelpers
     <div class="form-group row">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Does your view contain a @model directive?

Comment: @Marcoyes, I added "@model EmployeeCreateViewModel", and in my viewport inject                                                         
    "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.TagHelpers"

Comment: Is this only an issue with IntelliSense or is the tag helper also not being rendered properly?

Comment: @poke it is in only tag helpers at ASp.Net Core

Comment: and when I run the app  at google-chrome  display same tag that is not converted to tag HTML

Comment: and I follow these steps at this link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924211/net-core-tag-helper-intellisense-and-color-coding-not-working

Comment: Could you post a photo of your directory structure for your views where we can see the `_ViewImports.cshtml` and the view you are trying to use the tag helper in?

Comment: @poke [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYR9t.png] this is viewports

Comment: Hmm, that’s very odd. Could you also posts the contents of your `.csproj` file just to be safe that there’s not some incomplete stuff?

Comment: I forget to say, I use visual studio 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps to solve the problem.

1.Install Razor tool from package manager console. It is pre-release for now

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools –Pre`

2.Download and install Razor Language Services from marketplace. (Your visual studio instance should be closed)

After restart visual studio, intellisense and coloring should be working for tag helpers.

Comment: I really install Razor Tool and Razor Language Services, but not working until now